en el sidebar de genexus 18, se creó un item 'Datos', cómo se hace para crear un subitem dentro del item?
trabajando en una aplicación web en genexus 18, agregué en el sidebar los items que necesito (en el data provider)
Necesito saber como cargarle los subitems al item 'Ayuda' (cuando se despliega 'Ayuda')


SidebarItems
{
    SidebarItem
    {
        id = !'Ayuda'
        title = !'Ayuda'
        hasSubItems = true
        SidebarSubItems
        {
            SubItem
            {
                id = !'SubItem1'
                title = !'SubItem1'
            }
            SubItem
            {
                id = !'SubItem2'
                title = !'SubItem2'
            }

        }
    }
}

Te dejo también como sería si quisieras agregar más subsubitems y/o las demás propiedades de los items:
SidebarItems
{
    SidebarItem
    {
        id = /*id value*/
        title = /*title value*/
        icon = /*icon value*/
        target = /*target value*/
        hasSubItems = /*has Sub Items value*/
        SidebarSubItems
        {
            SubItem
            {
                id = /*id value*/
                title = /*title value*/
                target = /*target value*/
                hasSubItems = /*has Sub Items value*/
                SidebarSubSubItems
                {
                    SubSubItem
                    {
                        id = /*id value*/
                        title = /*title value*/
                        target = /*target value*/
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        activeItem = /*active Item value*/
    }
}


Genial, muchas gracias!!!

Nestor, te recomiendo leer el recorrido de bienvenida en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y que aceptes la respuesta en caso de que haya solucionado tu problema

Guido, luego de hacer lo que indicaste (y funcionó excelente) me surgió otra duda. uno de los sub items llama a un web panel y lo hace de forma correcta, el tema es que en este caso necesitaría que se abriera como un popup. cómo se puede hacer?

Podrías crear un WebPanel, por ej: WebPanelPrueba que en el evento Start tenga el siguiente código &Window.Object = WebPanelQueQuieresLlamarComoPopUp.Create() &Window.Open() y en el target del item en el Sidebar llamas a WebPanelPrueba.Link()
